# The best overloaded method match for … has some invalid arguments C#

Tags: c#

```
public static void masodmegold(double a,double b,double c)
{
     double x0, x1, x2;
     double gyokalatt = b * b - 4 * a * c;

     if (gyokalatt > 0)
     {
          x1 = ( -b + Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
          x2 = ( -b - Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
          Console.WriteLine("két gyök: ", x1, x2);
     }
     else if (gyokalatt == 0)
     {
          x0 = ( -b / (2 * a));
          Console.WriteLine("egy gyök: ", x0);
     }
     else 
     {
          Console.WriteLine("blabla!");    
     }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.WriteLine(masodmegold(1,-4,3));
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And there are two errors

Error 1

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Console.WriteLine(string,
>   params object[])' has some invalid arguments

Error 2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'string'

Comment: change Console.WriteLine(masodmegold(1,-4,3)); to masodmegold(1,-4,3);

Comment: What do you expect `Console.WriteLine(masodmegold(1,-4,3));` to do given that `masodmegold` is a void method?

Comment: just call your method... The method itself is printing a line of output in each case!

Answer (score 1):

Your `masodmegold` method returns void,See `public static void masodmegold` either you need to change return type void to something

```
public static string masodmegold(double a,double b,double c)
{ 
 //Your code here 
 //change  Console.WriteLine("két gyök: ", x1, x2); to Cnsole.WriteLine("két gyök: "+ x1+""+ x2);
 return "Some string you want to print"
}
```

Or in main you can call it like directly without changing its return type,

```
masodmegold(1,-4,3)
```

`Console.writeline()` expects a parameter, you are passing `masodmegold(1,-4,3)` with return type as void, which is equivalent to  `Console.writeline(void)`. So you getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `masodmegold` has type void and it does not return anything. So Just try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     masodmegold(1, -4, 3);
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Also in this line:

```
else if (gyokalatt == 0)
{
     x0 = ( -b / (2 * a));
     Console.WriteLine("egy gyök: ", x0);
}
```

Comparison of floating point with equality operator possible loss of precision while rounding values, it is better to use it in this way:

```
else if (Math.Abs(gyokalatt) < 0.001)
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line causing compilation errors:

```
Console.WriteLine(masodmegold(1,-4,3));
```

It shoult be just

```
masodmegold(1,-4,3);
```

Your `masodmegold` method has type `void` so it doesn't returns anythig - thus you have nothing to pass to `ConsoleWriteLine` after this method execution.

You should just call the method itself, without passing it as argument to `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 0):

**Error 1**
The way you build your strings are wrong, try something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("két gyök: " + x1 + " " + x2);
```

You could also look into the string.Format method.

**Error 2**
Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    masodmegold(1,-4,3);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("egy gyök: ", x0);
```

We can do it like that:

```
Console.WriteLine("egy gyök: {0}", x0);
```

This line:

```
Console.WriteLine(masodmegold(1,-4,3));
```

We should know the method `masodmegold` return nothing, cause the the program don't know which match the method named `WriteLine`.